# Need multiple Drag & Drop elements into droppable panel. Can someone to help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I made a drag & drop element with contenteditable in JQuery UI, but i need  multiple drag & drop into droppable panel. is there any solution to solve?

Here is code below:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="tempMain">
<div id="textTemp" class="temp">
    <div>Text</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="temEditor"><div id="tempEditorView"></div></div></div>

$(function(){$("#textTemp").draggable({
helper: "clone",
zIndex: 2500,
});
$( "#tempEditorView" ).droppable({
accept: '#textTemp',
drop: function( event, ui ) {
var html = '<div id="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; 
margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true"
style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p><div
style="padding:20px;" class="tempDraggableArea"></div></div>';
$(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
}
});
$('#tempEditorView').sortable({
handle: '.tempDraggableArea'
});
});
```

Check it in https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/5fge8Lzc/

Comment: Is this the one that you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/5fge8Lzc/1/

Comment: Thank you soo much dear, you saved my time.. I didn't noticed that i have placed id instead of class..

Comment: but i mean to change the "var html" for the relevant draggable "<div class="temp">. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change html content based on dragged element using id of that element as follows:

```
$( "#tempEditorView" ).droppable({
        accept: '.temp',
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var html = "";
      if(ui.draggable.attr("id")=="textTemp"){
      html = '<div id="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here.</p><div style="padding:20px;" class="tempDraggableArea"></div></div>';
      }else if(ui.draggable.attr("id")=="textTemp1"){
      html = '<div id="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here1.</p><div style="padding:20px;" class="tempDraggableArea"></div></div>';
      }else if(ui.draggable.attr("id")=="textTemp2"){
      html = '<div id="test" style="background: #eee; width: 80%; margin: 10px auto; padding: 10px;"><p contenteditable="true" style="padding: 5px;">Add your text here2.</p><div style="padding:20px;" class="tempDraggableArea"></div></div>';
      }
  $(html).appendTo(this).hide().slideDown();
      }
    });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5fge8Lzc/6/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot dear, this is what i needed.. Good work brother!